# Is NetBeans updatable by some means?

Tags: netbeans

I am currently working on NetBeans 7.0 it did not have HTML5 and CSS3 support, but the latest release [NetBeans 7.1.1](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) supports it.

Problem is to update to the latest version i have to download whole package of `167MB` (*for only JavaEE*).
Is there a way to just update to the latest version in netbeans without downloading whole installer because it is not a worth to download whole package with a slow Internet connection of 256kbps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/install.html#upgrading says

> Incremental version upgrades of the IDE cannot be performed at this time. To upgrade to the most recent version you must download the latest installer.

[edit]

Hm... a bit confusing. [Here](http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Update-7-1-gt-7-1-1-done-automatically-td5535254.html) it says, that you just need to update, only thing which won't get updated, is the splash screen. I would try an update and see if the needed functionality is provided.

Comment: In the second link it refer to an upgrade of 7.1 to 7.1.1. this is possible but not for 7.0 to 7.1.

Comment: So, in simple, it means that i would upgrade from `7.x.y >> 7.x.z` but not from `7.x to 7.y`.